# Tool to diff two CSS elements

Tags: css

I have two div's that display slightly differently, I have looked through each of their CSS properties and they appear to be the same, however I am wondering if I've overlooked something.

Is there a tool that will basically diff the CSS of two different elements?

Preferably integrated into the browser.

**EDIT**

I have used Chrome's built in dev tools and gone through the computed styles area and manually compared each property (IE div.A font-weight:normal; div.B font-weight:normal etc...)

I am looking for a tool that essentially says "Select Element A and B", and shoots out a list of differences. Like a Winmerge comparison or something like that.

Comment: You have looked through their properties how?

Comment: use Firebug for firefox and web developer tool for IE

Comment: @Ahsan Rathod: Can you show us how you use Firebug/F12 to compare the styles of two elements side-by-side?

Comment: Have you checked surrounding parent and child elements? Perhaps the difference is from a parent's padding or a child's width which makes one of the two divs look dissimilar.

Comment: If you are using firefox install Firebug extension as addon by downloading it from firefox website. And If you are suing IE 8 then Web Developer tool is present in IE8.

Comment: @Nathan In Chrome: right click the DIV -> Inspect element. Then open "Computed style", check "show inherited". Copy the list into a text-file. Repeat for second DIV. Then compare the text-files.

Comment: @ BoltClock: You can inspect each element having styles applied on it.

Comment: I've used @Šime Vidas suggestion and it has worked. I am still looking for a tool to do this if it exists.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592473/difference-between-two-element-styles-with-google-chrome/12596540) and, as a result, I created a script that compares two elements in Chrome (you will find it in the linked answer). Also, based on said script, I created a handy Chrome DevTools Extension ["CSS Diff"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-diff/pefnhibkhcfooofgmgoipfpcojnhhljm).

[image: CSS Diff in action]

Comment: Super, I'm just wondering if it could be applied to two elements in different pages open in chrome ?

Comment: The link is broken, but I found a new link here: https://github.com/kdzwinel/CSS-Diff

Answer (score 3):

I think [Firediff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firediff/) is what you want. While it doesn't compare two elements, but it kind'of logs DOM changes, so that you can compare those logs to see what's happening.

Also you can go to computed style in Firebug, and copy/paste computed style of each div into a different notepad file, and then compare those files using a file comparison tool. [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is really cool.

Answer (score 0):

div tags sometime behave different with same properties. The reason is your other code may be affecting it. In Firefox you can use firebug. the important thing in my opineon is you need to check the code around divs which is affecting their behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Code Cola](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lomkpheldlbkkfiifcbfifipaofnmnkn) extension for Google Chrome. Very good and powerfull tool. Recomend for everybody.

Comment: not actually what I wanted to solve this problem, but is a very cool tool

Answer (score -3):

Beyond compare is the tool for comparing css or any kind of file