# Difference between two element styles with Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, styles, google-chrome-devtools

I use Google Chrome developer tools and I am constantly inspecting one element against another back and forth to find out what may be causing a particular styling issue.

It would be nice to compare the differences in style between element 1 and element 2.

Can this be done with chrome currently or via some workaround? Is there a tool out there that can do what I am looking for?

*Current example of style difference is that I have an inline `H4` next to a `A` where the `A` is appearing higher in vertical alignment. I am not seeking a solution in this question as I will sort it out.*

Answer (score 150, accepted):

---

**Update:** As a result of this discussion, the "[CSS Diff](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-diff/bnkooidmjbobfbgncondmfoajbpafjio)" Chrome extension was created.

[image]

---

Great question and cool idea for extension!

**Proof of concept**

As a proof of concept, we can do a small trick here and avoid creating extension. Chrome keeps elements you select via 'inspect element' button in variables. Last selected element in `$0`, one before that in `$1` etc. Basing on this, I've created a small snippet that compares last two inspected elements:

```
(function(a,b){    
    var aComputed = getComputedStyle(a);
    var bComputed = getComputedStyle(b);

    console.log('------------------------------------------');
    console.log('You are comparing: ');
    console.log('A:', a);
    console.log('B:', b);
    console.log('------------------------------------------');

    for(var aname in aComputed) {
        var avalue = aComputed[aname];
        var bvalue = bComputed[aname];

        if( aname === 'length' || aname === 'cssText' || typeof avalue === "function" ) {
            continue;
        }
        
        if( avalue !== bvalue ) {
            console.warn('Attribute ' + aname + ' differs: ');
            console.log('A:', avalue);
            console.log('B:', bvalue);
        }
    }

    console.log('------------------------------------------');
})($0,$1);
```

**How to use it?**

Inspect two elements you want to compare, one after another, and paste the code above to console.

**Result**

[image: sample output from provided snippet]

Comment: Fantastic. Have posted a follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611440/accessing-chromes-last-inspected-element-being-0-and-1-via-js

Comment: Since I ended up creating chrome extension for this, my original answer was updated.

Comment: Now, if it could be extended to compare styles between two different pages, I'd pay money for it.

Comment: Very cool, except I need the same to compare pages between tabs - i.e. dev site to QA site comparision

Comment: @GeoffreyHudik CSS Diff extension now works between the tabs - check it out.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel I tried it yesterday and it hasn't been updated since then. Just realized that it's not working for me for the same page even - then again I may be doing it wrong... just quickly read through documentation.

Comment: If you don't mind using Firefox, I added an feature that lets you right click, set "A" node, right click, set "B" node, and compare attributes, css for the element *and its children*: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devtools-tweaks/

Comment: @KonradDzwinel where and how i cant find it ?

Comment: @KonradDzwinel  404 ...  are you sure it's still available ?

Comment: link is currently dead

Comment: @Dror This is a [css diff chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-diff/bnkooidmjbobfbgncondmfoajbpafjio?hl=en) no clue whether it is the same one.

Comment: CSS diff extension seems to not be woking - I didn't seen CSS diff tab in devtools :-(. I've used it in the past and was very satisfied. I cannot find it any more.

Comment: Manually installed version 0.33.0 from github https://github.com/kdzwinel/CSS-Diff was working. It's on your own risk.

Comment: here's a version that prints using console.table instead https://gist.github.com/jakedowns/384d6aa84db9f43c31616a5c88cf3649

Comment: I get a tab in chrome dev tools but its just blank..

Comment: @KonradDzwinel Your link goes to the wrong Chrome extension!! Can you please update your answer to point to your [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kdzwinel/CSS-Diff), and perhaps include [instructions to install unpacked extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/development-basics/#load-unpacked)