# Accessing Chrome's last inspected element being $0 and $1 via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Can Chrome's last inspected elements be access with javascript?

Background, trying to integrate this into a Debug.js file to be called onclick.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/12596540/511438

I am trying to integrate the function provided above to execute on a clickable element.

Here is my attempt which results in undefined even though i have inspected elements prior to executing this.

```
$(document).on('click', "#debugelements", 
    function () { CompareElements(window.$0, window.$1); });
```

and

```
function CompareElements(a, b)
{
... as per the answer above.
}
```

i suspect $0 is inaccessable to javascript. Is there a way to do this in javascript without pasting the whole function into the Chrome console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that only Chrome Extensions have access to these variables. There is a sample extension that makes use of `$0`, it's called 'Chrome Query' and is available on [samples page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html). I took it's code, modified a little and ended up with [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pefnhibkhcfooofgmgoipfpcojnhhljm). The code is available on [github](https://github.com/kdzwinel/CSS-Diff). I'm not sure if it's extra useful in current form, but there is a lot of space for improvement. Table instead of a tree should be more readable, I'll try to make it happen next week.

[image: screenshot from CSS Diff extension]

Comment: fantastic start. Will move over to github to work with you on this.